# TMG/ISA FWX_E_NETWORK_RULES_DENIED

Tags: firewall, isa-server, microsoft-ftmg-2010

I've got three disparit networks that all terminate at a TMG machine. I am trying to communicate between two of these networks, but the TMG firewall keeps dropping the connection as `FWX_E_NETWORK_RULES_DENIED`.

[image: TMG dropping packets]

This is seriously confusing, as I've gone and set up the network rules as follows:

[image: TMG rules permitting traffic]

Clearly it's set to permit all traffic between these two networks. But the firewall is still dropping it. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Network Rule" you show is actually a "Firewall Rule".

As well as the firewall rule you have set up you also need a network rule that tells TMG what the relationship is between the two networks i.e. whether traffic should be routed or NAT'd

Go to Network -> Network rules and add a rule in and it should start working

Answer (score 1):

`FWX_E_NETWORK_RULES_DENIED` is not actually a drop message based on any firewall rules, but rather network rules.

From Networking > Network Rules, go to your network definition, and make sure that the Source Network has ALL of the Destination Networks selected.

[image]

The firewall rules are useless if you don't have the source/destination networks configured correctly in the network setup.